# Add https to aws ec2 server when client side is adroid application

Tags: node.js, android-studio, amazon-ec2

How to add HTTPS to nodejs aws ec2 server ..?The problem is we don't have domain name  as the client side is android application .So is it possible to get secured connection between android app and aws server ?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, though it would be better if you have a domain.

One solution would be:

Create a Cloudfront distribution which allows `put` `head` and etc. And make ec2 your origin. And then you can communicate through https://??????.cloudfront.net with secure features.